Highlight full comment that contains keyword in custom color
I want to highlight a comment with a custom color when the comment contains a specified keyword, e.g. todo.
I want to highlight the entire comment, not just the keyword itself.
How to do that in VS Code?
IntelliJ has that feature, but I'm testing VS Code because it has much better Cython support.

Have you looked at the Highlight extension

this works, but it seems when one adds a new comment with a keyword this does NOT immediately highlight the line, only after restarting the app... any workarounds?

did you use the one from spampinato

yes, from Fabio Spampinato

I have copy/pasted the TODO example setting from the README and it highlights these lines while I type
